# How to include a pdf in LaTex along with other texts on the same page

Tags: pdfpages

I already know how to include pages of a pdf file into a LaTex document. However, I actually want to include a pdf along with some other texts, such as a topic, on the same page. Can anyone please give me the correct code that I should write?

Comment: You can include a pdf as graphic: `\includegraphics[width=6cm]{somepdf}`

Comment: @Ulrike: Thanks.